# How to convert 2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z into the format YYYY-MM-DD in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can I convert the date string `2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z` into the format YYYY-MM-DD in Node.js?

Answer (score 15):

> **Note:** [Moment is in maintenance mode](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/). Consider using one of the modern alternatives below, such as [datefns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73223895/12860895).

You can use Moment.

1. Install Moment:

   ```bash
   npm install moment
   ```
2. Import Moment into your JavaScript file:

   ```js
   import moment from "moment";
   ```
3. Use the following code to convert it:

   ```js
   moment("2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z").utc().format('YYYY-MM-DD') // 2021-07-14
   ```

Comment: Helpful with the date format documentation from the original website: https://momentjs.com/docs/

Answer (score 3):

You can use [datefns](https://date-fns.org).

```js
import {format} from 'date-fns';
console.log(format(new Date("2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z"), 'p, dd/MM/YYYY'));
```

Answer (score 2):

A great blog

https://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format

wanted format :
YYYY-MM-DD

using :

1. internal script
2. external script

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

    <!--... external javascript ...-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://stevenlevithan.com/assets/misc/date.format.js"></script>

    <h2>JavaScript new Date() - YYYY-MM-DD </h2>
    <p id="demo1"></p>
    <p id="demo2"></p>
    <p id="demo3"></p>
    
    <script>
    const d1 = new Date("2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z")

    // 01 - input
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = d1;

    function formatDate(date) {
      var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

      if (month.length < 2) 
        month = '0' + month;
      if (day.length < 2) 
        day = '0' + day;

      return [year, month, day].join('-');
    }

    // 02 - using function formatDate
    var result2 = formatDate(d1);

    console.log(result2);
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = result2;

    // 03 - external javascript 
    var result3 =d1.format("yyyy/mm/dd");
    document.getElementById("demo3").innerHTML = result3;

    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

OUTPUT :

```
Wed Jul 14 2021 02:00:00 GMT+0200 (Central European Summer Time)
2021-07-14
2021-07-14
```

Answer (score 0):

no need to use third party libraries, just use string slicing in JavaScript. here is the code

```js
const dateString = '2023-08-01T12:48:50Z';
const indexOfT = dateString.indexOf('T');
const dateWithoutTime = dateString.substring(0, indexOfT);

console.log(dateWithoutTime); // Output: 2023-08-01
```

Answer (score 0):

`2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z` is a Date string in the [ISO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format. You can just [`String#slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice) the first 10 characters in order to get the `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

```js
const dateString = '2021-07-14T00:00:00.000Z';
const formattedDate = dateString.slice(0, 10);

console.log(formattedDate); // "2021-07-14"
```